# Store timestamp when the app is in background. React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

EDITED: I want to store a timestamp when the react native app goes into the background, to see if re-login is needed. I use the async storage to save the timestamp on the device, with help of the appstate functionality. 
But the getItem and setItem code never executes. any idea why ?

```
componentDidMount() {
    AppState.addEventListener('change', this._handleAppStateChange);
}
 _handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState: any) => {

    if (
        this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) &&
        nextAppState === 'active'
    ) {
        this.getTime();
        this.checkTimeStamp();
        console.log(this.state.time, 'time var');
        console.log('app is active, and has been in the background');
    } else if (
        this.state.appState == 'active' &&
        nextAppState == 'active'
    ) {
        this.setTime();
        this.checkTimeStamp();
        console.log(this.state.time, 'time var');
        console.log('app is active, and just opened.');
    } else {
        this.setTime()
            //sets the timestamp
        console.log('app in background or closed');
    }
    this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
};

async setTime() {
    let seconds = this.generateTime();
    try {
        const val = await AsyncStorage.setItem('time', seconds.toString());
        this.setState({ time: Number(val) });

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('onRejected function called: ' + error);
    }
}

async getTime() {
    let please = await AsyncStorage.getItem('time');
    this.setState({ time: Number(please) });
    console.log(this.state.time, 'time var');
```

}

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at AppState https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate
It allows you to listen for "active"/"background" state changes.

Comment: Yeah. Sounds like that's the way to go. Was trying to simplify it to much. Any idea how to see if the app is about to be closed, and do some last second code runs?

Comment: well, `componentWillUnmount` would be the place to do it, but why would you set state on a component that is about to unmount?

Comment: because, i want to set the timestamp when the app goes to the background, not before.